# Unable to make Save Dialog Save file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I am trying to save a list of random numbers to a text file, the amount of random numbers is chosen by the user (if they input the number 2, then 2 random numbers are written to the file). I have gotten the numbers to output into a text file within Visual Studio's default bin directory, however when I try to allow for the user to choose where to save the file, even after selecting the desired directory and file name and clicking the save button, the file does not appear within explorer

here is what  have thus far:

```
 private void writeToFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declare streamwriter object
            StreamWriter outputFile;
            outputFile = File.CreateText("Random.txt");

            //declare my counter, random object, and make variable to store user input
            Random rand = new Random();
            int desiredEntries;
            int.TryParse(numberOfEntriesTextbox.Text, out desiredEntries);
            int counter = 1;

            //take user input and generate numbers until user input is equal to counter
            while(counter <= desiredEntries)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(rand.Next(100));
                counter++;
            }

            //save resulting file in a txt document
            if (saveRandomFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                outputFile = File.CreateText(saveRandomFileDialog.FileName);
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("you suck");
            }
            outputFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error or just not saving (i.e. showing the `you suck` message)?

Comment: The way I have it above, the program functions normally after I choose to save the file, so it doesn't show the "you suck" message, and doesn't throw an exception, but it doesn't save the file.

Comment: Ask them where to save it first. Then pass the filename to the createtext before writing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening a file:

```
    outputFile = File.CreateText("Random.txt");
```

Writing to that file, and then *after* you write to the file, you *then* ask the user where they want to save the file. I see a problem here. :)

Replace the above line with this one:

```
        outputFile = File.CreateText(saveRandomFileDialog.FileName);
```

Edit:

Basically, your code should look like this (I removed the you suck part, but feel free to insult your users if you wish) :)

```
if (saveRandomFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) {
    return;                
}

using (StreamWriter outputFile = File.CreateText(saveRandomFileDialog.FileName)) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int desiredEntries;
    int.TryParse(numberOfEntriesTextbox.Text, out desiredEntries);
    int counter = 1;

    while (counter <= desiredEntries) {
        outputFile.WriteLine(rand.Next(100));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, Visual Studio throws an exception

Comment: What exception would that be?

Comment: If the op just replaces that line where it is in the current code, the saveRandomFileDialog will not have a file name set yet. The save location needs to be set before the file is even created.

Comment: @JasonDown, yeah, I kind of assumed moving the declaration was implied, but then decided, well, maybe not. :)

Comment: AH OKay. . . I was asking where to save it AFTER I wrote it!!!! Now I understand.